# Is this question wrong? "So need I"

Tags: exam-questions

In an online English test, there was this question:

> Choose the correct variant
>
> -I needed to have my hair cut
>
> A) So need I
> B) So didn't she
> C) But my sister did
> D) Neither did she
> E) And my sister did

In my opinion, the correct answer should have been "So did I" but it wasn't among the variants. So I choose variant A. I'm not sure if native speakers use "So need I" but it just seems like the only one that makes sense in that question.

However, the answer turns out to be E.
And I just can't comprehend why.
I mean, everything aside, isn't it logically incorrect to choose E in that context?

Comment: It's a very poor quality test, because *none* of the proposed "continuations" are particularly idiomatic. Given that the word ***so*** has been included in a couple of the (ungrammatical) suggestions, they should have offered **F) *...and so did my sister.*** I'd bet any money this test was composed by a non-native speaker with limited fluency in English, so there's precious little to be learned from it.

Comment: Please explain what the book means by "variant". We can't answer if we don't know what that is. Do you perhaps mean "alternative" instead of "variant"?

Comment: If this came from a book, get a different book. If this came from a teacher, get a different teacher.

Comment: "So did I" would only make sense if the first sentence was about someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I would have had no idea how to answer that question.  It doesn't make sense.  I don't even know what "variant" means in this context.  C,D and E are all correct expressions, but none of them are a variation of the given phrase.

I suppose that E is the only answer that could possibly be a *continuation* of the phrase. It should really have been

> E) ..., and my sister did too.

A and B are not idiomatic phrases. In C the use of "But" doesn't match with the uncontrasting "my sister did" and in D the use of "Neither" doesn't match the postive sense in the given phrase.

So E is the only possible continuation, but as I said, it needs "too" at the end.